# sparse non-negative least squares in C++

Tags: c++, math, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm looking for a software package to solve a *very large*, sparse non-linear least squares problem in C++.  I've come across a large number of modern linalg libraries in C++ (eigen, armadillo, boost, etc.), but none seem to have such a solver (or even a regular least-squares solver) built in.  I'd really like to avoid a bunch of messy calls to an old C / Fortran interface if possible. Thanks!

Comment: you can take a look at [SuiteSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use the **general-purpose NLP solver** [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) written in C++. It is the most robust solver among those I have tried and it is meant and successfully used on *very large* problems.

A change in requirements (e.g. adding constraints) would be no problem if you use the general-purpose IPOPT.

The time consuming part of the solution procedure is to solve the linear systems in each iteration step so it's worth getting the best linear solver + LinAlg package for your platform.

Unfortunately IPOPT calls Fortran subroutines internally so you will need a Fortran compiler which is sort of a pain.

If IPOPT is not enough, you will have to look for a problem specific solver.

Comment: Hi @Ali.  This makes sense, but my only concern is that adding the non-negativity constraint for all variables might introduce a lot of overhead, whereas a dedicated non-negative least squares solver might incorporate these constraints more efficiently.  Anyway, if there are no more suggestions in the next day or so I'll mark you answer as accepted; thanks!

Comment: @nomad Yes, it can easily happen that IPOPT is not the best tool for you. How big are your problems?

Comment: My matrix is 50M by 96K with a few hundred entries per column.  So it's incredibly sparse, but *huge*.

Comment: That's really HUGE. Nevertheless, I would try MA57 with METIS. The [doc](http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node6.html) explicitly says that the linear solver has a huge impact on the performance. Please let me know how things turned out for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need constraints, try out [Ceres](https://code.google.com/p/ceres-solver/) or [g2o](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o). Both build on top of Eigen and can utilize sparse matrix solvers, i.e. [SuiteSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/) and friends.